# mojs change shape of Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to change the shape of an object in mojs?

Something like the following:

```
var shape = new mojs.Shape({
    shape:      'circle',
    fill:       'red',
    radius:     '20',
});

// after some timeout or delay
shape.shapeModule = 'rect';
```

Not sure if this is possible or not. Perhaps it would be easier to create both shapes and fade out the circle and fade in the new rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the creator of the mojs library, it turns out this is not currently possible with mojs. There may be changes in the future that allow this, but there is currently no way to change the shape of an object.

Comment: I thought `shape.tune({shape: 'rect'})` would do the trick but it didn't work.

Comment: I expected it would as well, but the only property that is not tunable is the shape property. See here for more info: https://github.com/legomushroom/mojs/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options as per the api docs: https://mojs.github.io/api/modules/shape/

```
     // Shape name. {String} [ 'circle' | 'rect' | 'polygon' | 'line' | 'cross' | 'equal' | 'curve' | 'zigzag' | '*custom defined name*' ]
  shape: 'circle',
```